# mysql.sock file missing from MAMP

Tags: mysql, mamp, laravel-5

I am using:

- MAMP 3.0.7.3
- OSX 10.10.2
- laravel/homestead (vagrant) to host my site locally

Specifically, the error I get is:

> PDOException in Connector.php line 47:
>   SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

In my Laravel project, in config/database.php, I have:

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'unix_socket' => '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock',
            'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'stocks'),
            'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'stock_admin'),
            'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'password'),
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
            'strict'    => false,
        ],
```

In my .env file:

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=KGY7geRpdCKywyqFhlBFvfNX1g5wXal0

DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_DATABASE=stocks
DB_USERNAME=stock_admin
DB_PASSWORD=password

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
```

I have tried changing DB_HOST between localhost and 127.0.0.1 to no avail.

I have installed mysql through brew. 
The actual file /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock does not exist when I look for it in the finder.

I have checked my /Applications/MAMP/bin files:

startmysql.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe --port=3306 --socket=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock --pid-file=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.pid --log-error=/Applications/MAMP/logs/mysql_error_log &
```

and stopMysql.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqladmin -u root -proot --socket=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock shutdown
```

I have also tried creating a symbolic link with these commands:

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock /tmp/mysql.sock
```

and

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock /var/tmp/mysql.sock
```

and it does not appear to work.

I understand the mysql.sock file is created dynamically, but it does not appear to happen in my case. I am unsure how to proceed from here; it feels as though I have tried everything. Any help is appreciated.